# Simplify the function by Karnaugh map

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Simplify the function by karnaugh map : : $- x_1'x_2' + x_1x_3x_4 + x_1x_2x_4+ x_1x_2x_4'+x_2'x_3$

attempt: $-x_1x_2'+x_1x_3x_4+x_1x_2(x_4'+x_4)+x_2'x_3
=-x_1x_2'+x_1x_3x_4+x_1x_2+x_2'x_3=x_1(x_2-x_2')+x_1x_3x_4+x_2'x_3$

what we do next  can  any one help me please
can any one drew the table for this

Comment: first i need simplifciation

Comment: i dont how to draw here

Comment: @alex ..can you please help me to solve this

Comment: I am hesitant to make your homework. The process is to first draw the KV map and then use it to simplify. The purpose of the map is to identify adjacent terms which can be merged. That's what you did in your attempt.